# The bot crashes whe3n i use user id

Tags: javascript, discord.js, crash, bots

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

const config = require('../config.json');
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

```
if(!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS, true)) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')
if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS, true)) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the permissions.')

const member = message.mentions.members.first();

if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please specify a user');





let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

if(!reason) reason = 'Unspecified';

message.guild.members.unban(`${member}`, `${reason}`)
.catch(err => {
    if(err) return message.channel.send('Something went wrong')
})

let banembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Member Unbanned')
.addField('User Unbanned', member)
.addField('Unbanned by', message.author)
.addField('Reason', reason)
.setFooter('Time Unbanned', client.user.displayAvatarURL())
.setTimestamp()

message.channel.send(banembed);
```

}

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `message.mentions.members.first()` which is referring to a pinged person. To use their ID's you can use `.fetch` or `cache.get`

```js
const member = await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])
const member = await message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

also you can use them on the same line using `or` `||`

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]) || await message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

I only don't know if its going to work with `unban` because the bot and the user should on the same server

Comment: no need to await getting a member from the cache.